# User prompt via notification - feedback to user needed?

Tags: android, notifications

my question is related to android notifications.

In my app, users are prompted several times a day to enter data (that is then transferred to a server application) by notifications. So, as soon as the user clicks on a notification, an activity is started, where the user enters some data. After clicking the report button, the data is uploaded (and the notification is cleared). 
Do I have to tell the user that his data entry is archived or uploaded or whatever (via a Toast or Dialog for example)?

Is there any best practices related to giving user feedback after reacting to an app-notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Android Design Patterns Guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/confirming-acknowledging.html), they have a nice flowchart for use if you are unsure whether you need to give feedback. From your description, I'd guess it hits "NO" on block four(possibly block three if you want an undo option), so you should give lightweight feedback. A toast or dialog is great for this, like you suggested.